# why was I not automatically prompted to update?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu

### initial question

I was bragging on IRC about how NoModeSet finally allowed me to boot normally for the first time without tricking my graphics drivers not to run, and was told to run the following command:

```
jay@KingdomClubs:~$ uname -a && lsb_release -a && sudo lshw -C video
Linux KingdomClubs 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:44:00 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
[sudo] password for jay:
  *-display UNCLAIMED      
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G72 [GeForce 7350 LE]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c0000-dffff
jay@KingdomClubs:~$
```

I was told I wasn't up to date, and hadn't installed nVidia drivers. Indeed it seemed strange because I remember checking the lubuntu site and apparently they're latest LTS version was 18.04.2

I remember at one point being prompted to update automatically but I guess it didn't anymore. I'm not sure why. Anyway I ran the following as suggested on IRC:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

It's about 24% so hopefully that's a step in the right direction. Although it's unclear to me if this will install nVidia drivers. Would anyone know what I search in Synaptic Package Manager to get those?

IRC also suggested following:

```
apt full-upgrade
```

I assume I would precede that with 'sudo' to give root permission? But I am not sure what diff between "upgrade" and "full-upgrade" would be. Could anyone explain that?

I already used SPM to verify "ubuntu-drivers" was installed in response to [How do I fix a frozen black screen on Lubuntu startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077616/how-do-i-fix-a-frozen-black-screen-on-lubuntu-startup) which I thought meant that my video card driver software would be up to date but I guess I am wrong...

Or... is it possibly something to do with needing to activate it via the "autoinstall" command?

---

### 1st reply, to guiver

"if this is needed" sounds like it won't remove packages unless they interfere with system upgrade? I guess you would only do a normal "upgrade" if you were in the middle of something and didn't want to reboot right then. I guess I will run that next.

I got the following screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxlWp.png transcribed below:

```
Package configuration

 ┌──────────────────────────┤ Configuring grub-pc ├──────────────────────────┐
 │ A new version (/tmp/grub.SnIFfR3w39) of configuration file                │ 
 │ /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has   │ 
 │ been locally modified.                                                    │ 
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ What do you want to do about modified configuration file grub?            │ 
 │                                                                           │ 
 │           install the package maintainer's version                        │ 
 │           keep the local version currently installed                      │ 
 │           show the differences between the versions                       │ 
 │           show a side-by-side difference between the versions             │ 
 │           show a 3-way difference between available versions              │ 
 │           do a 3-way merge between available versions                     │ 
 │           start a new shell to examine the situation                      │ 
 │                                                                           │ 
 │                                                                           │ 
 │                                  <Ok>                                     │ 
 │                                                                           │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I don't know if there was any major change to the grub file between 18.04.1 and 18.04.2 but it seems like the safe bet might be to take the first option (package maintainer's version) and then if I get the same problems at bootup as before, then redo my steps with switching quiet splash to nodemodeset?

On IRC it was recommended I just keep the local one, implying that there wasn't anything changed though, so I guess I'll do that for now?

I'm sure if I do `full-upgrade` it will just prompt me again anyway. Options 3-7 I'm not sure I even want to think about, they sound complex.

---

Comment: Yes you need `sudo apt full-upgrade`, but if you check your documentation (`man apt`) you'll see *full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.*  or it performs all of upgrade and more. Upgrade has limits on what packages it can upgrade, full-upgrade or dist-upgrade do all.  They may require reboot, restarting of services etc which upgrade allows you to postpone those till a later more suitable time.

Comment: I have replied above. Is there a major diff between dist-upgrade and full-upgrade?

Comment: Questions on this site should be on a single topic, after a single response. The 'dist-upgrade' is mostly from `apt-get`, and in the `man apt-get` you get more detail.  It's my belief that in `apt` they do the same thing (the manual `man` page doesn't refer to dist-upgrade; it's there I think for people like me with fingers that know apt-get commands)  I would suggest sticking with package-maintainers version unless you have a reason not to; you can 'show differences' if it'll help you decide. I always add comments of date/who-made-change/why when I change something which i see in show-diffs.